# What kind of shower arm do I need?

Tags: plumbing, shower

I am remodeling my house and as part of the process I removed the shower arm to do some drywall repair in the area about 6 months ago. I didn't pay much attention to removing it at the time because I figured I would do some research to figure out what I needed later. Now that "later" is now, I am stumped trying to figure out what exactly I need to replace the shower arm/head. Every tutorial online includes a simple threaded piece in or on the wall that you screw an arm into. I have a very short copper stub that comes out of the wall. If I look inside, it's clearly not screwed into any threads, it looks like a solid piece of copper tubing that bends down.

[image: Copper Stub Out]

[image: Shows bend down into wall]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are pipe adapters and extenders that fit standard pipe thread, so you could find one to fit that pipe and adapt it to anything. There are also standard [45° (or 135°) shower elbows with female thread on one side and male on other](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B096VXXZD9) that **might** work.

You could also mount a [flexible shower hose](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07QR4KTYY) directly on that nipple.

[Above links shown as examples, only.]

That said, I see two issues:

- What is the *size* of that pipe nipple, and what thread does it have? This varies from region to region, and the easiest way to test would be to bring the old shower elbow to a hardware store.
- Copper pipe is soft, flexible, and eventually may crack and/or develop pinholes due to torsion and corrosion.

  How old is that fitting? How would you replace it if it requires repairs? Usually, there is a brass 90° fitting inside the wall, firmly attached, into which a shower elbow with two male ends is inserted. You might think about opening the wall and soldering in such a fitting for a *lasting* repair.

[image: shower fitting]